# << operator overloading as a class method in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload the << operator for my class Complex.

The prototype is the following:

```
void Complex::operator << (ostream &out)
{
    out << "The number is: (" << re <<", " << im <<")."<<endl;
}
```

It works, but I have to call it like this: object << cout for the standart output.
What can I do to make it work backwards, like cout << object?

I know that the 'this' pointer is by default the first parameter sent to the method so that's why the binary operator can work only obj << ostream. I overloaded it as a global function and there were no problems.

Is there a way to overload the << operator as a method and to call it ostream << obj?

Comment: You know there already is a [complex number](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) class in the standard library?

Comment: Yes. Complex class was just a simple example and the point of the question is how can I overload the operator as a method.

Comment: You have already found the problem - as a member function the parameters are in the wrong order. There is no way to change this. The closest you get is making it a `friend` function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading, ctrl  + f = stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just use the usual C++ pattern of *free function*. You can make it `friend` to your `Complex` class if you want to make `Complex` class's private data members visible to it, but usually a complex number class would expose public getters for real part and imaginary coefficient.

```
class Complex
{
  ....

   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Complex& c);
private:
   double re;
   double im;
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Complex& c)
{
    out << "The number is: (" << c.re << ", " << c.im << ").\n";
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a free stand `operator<<` function, try:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Complex& cm)
{
    out << "The number is: (" << cm.re <<", " << cm.im <<")." << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a global function:

```
void operator << (ostream& out, const Complex& complex)
{
     complex.operator<<(out);
}
```